# sed - trouble using a variable which is previously set with another variable

Tags: command-line, bash, sed, html

I would like to know why sed does not work when the value is set in var, $thecolor ?
(I cannot use an HTML parser for this).

The desired result is available without using a variable to set $STARTPATTERN:

```
$ STARTPATTERN='<span style=" color: #007000;">'
$ echo $STARTPATTERN
<span style=" color: #007000;">
$ echo $ENDPATTERN
</span>
$ echo '<p><span style=" color: #007000;">content words</span></p>' | sed -e "s%.*$STARTPATTERN\(.*\)$ENDPATTERN.*%\1%"   # % is the delimiter for sed
content words
```

But when using variable, thecolor:

```
$ echo $thecolor
#007000
$ STARTPATTERN="<span style=\" color: $thecolor;\">"
$ echo $STARTPATTERN
<span style=" color: #007000;">
$ echo $ENDPATTERN
</span>
$ echo '<p><span style=" color: #007000;">content words</span></p>' | sed -e "s%.*$STARTPATTERN\(.*\)$ENDPATTERN.*%\1%"
<p><span style=" color: #007000;">content words</span></p>
```

New information:

$thecolor is generated as:

```
$ contentLine='<p><span style=" color: #007000;">content words</span></p>'

$ thecolor=$(echo $contentLine | sed -nr '/<span style=\" color:/ s/.*<span style=\" color:([^"]+).*/\1/p' | sed 's/;//')
```

I retyped the contentLine by hand directly in the terminal and am getting the same error.

Trying debugg option for sed:

```
echo "$contentLine" | sed --debug -e "s%.*$STARTPATTERN\(.*\)$ENDPATTERN.*%\1%" 

SED PROGRAM:
  s/.*<span style=" color:  #007000;">\\(.*\\)<\/span>.*/\1/

INPUT:   'STDIN' line 1

PATTERN: <p><span style=" color: #007000;">content words</span></p>

COMMAND: s/.*<span style=" color:  #007000;">\\(.*\\)<\/span>.*/\1/

PATTERN: <p><span style=" color: #007000;">content words</span></p>

END-OF-CYCLE:
<p><span style=" color: #007000;">content words</span></p>
```

The solution posted by steeldriver works, but I would like to understand why the adding or subtracting the space does not show in echo $STARTPATTERN:

```
$ STARTPATTERN="<span style=\" color: $thecolor;\">"  # a space between color:_$thecolor
$ echo $STARTPATTERN
<span style=" color: #007000;">  # space between color:_#007000
$ echo '<p><span style=" color: #007000;">content words</span></p>' | sed -e "s%.*$STARTPATTERN\(.*\)$ENDPATTERN.*%\1%" 
<p><span style=" color: #007000;">content words</span></p>   # undesirable results
```

```
$ STARTPATTERN="<span style=\" color:$thecolor;\">"  # the space removed
$ echo $STARTPATTERN
<span style=" color: #007000;"> # STILL has space between color:_#007000
$ echo '<p><span style=" color: #007000;">content words</span></p>' | sed -e "s%.*$STARTPATTERN\(.*\)$ENDPATTERN.*%\1%"
content words     # desirable results
```

Comment: Can you show your variables definition? I'm testing your command and it works.

Comment: Yes there is maybe something weird going on with how the "thecolor" variable was set, it could have some garbage characters inside it that are now seen when doing `echo $STARTPATTERN` but are anyway there and causing problems later.

Comment: ... with a sufficiently recent version of sed, you can add the `--debug` option to see exactly what sed is seeing

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity  I retyped by hand, directly in the terminal, but am getting the same error. Any change you inadvertently fixed my code on your end?

Comment: When you extract the color value, `color:([^"]+).*` captures the space between the `:` and the `#007000`; then when you construct `STARTPATTERN="<span style=\" color: $thecolor;\">"` you add another space.

Comment: Thank you, @steeldriver, although that solves it, I am perplexed.  I have appended a question to my post.

Comment: @Insideup because the **unquoted** expansion in `echo $STARTPATTERN` is subject to word splitting, effectively replacing contiguous sequences of whitespace characters by single spaces - see for example [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68748/65304)